# `ActionController::API` ancestors are not updated once its class has been loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand why the `ActionController::API` ancestors are not updated once its class has been loaded, when a module is explicitly added to its hierarchy.

I have the following Railtie:

```rb
module MyModule
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "mymodule.initialize" do |app|
      # Force Rails to load view templates even in API mode
      if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 5
        puts ActionController::API.ancestors.include?(ActionView::Rendering)

        module ::ActionController
          module ApiRendering
            include ActionView::Rendering
          end
        end

        puts ActionController::API.ancestors.include?(ActionView::Rendering)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which displays:

```
false
false
```

If I comment the first `puts` (which trigger the load of `ActionController::API`), the output of the second `puts` changes:

```
true
```

In plain Ruby this kind of updates works well, so Rails must do something that I'm not familiar with.

```rb
module A; end
module B; end

class API
  include A
end

module A
  include B
end

API.ancestors.include?(B) # returns true
```

Context: `scout_apm` triggers this issue when required before `jbuilder` so I managed to reproduce a minimal scenario.

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/47699#issuecomment-1473533695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality works on ruby `3.0` or higher ([source](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html#include-and-prepend-now-affects-modules-including-the-receiver)). If you run the example code on version `2.7` you will get `false` as a result for the `API.ancestors.include?(B)`.

However there is a case when it wouldn't work even with new ruby versions and that is when those modules are both `ActiveSupport::Concern` which is true for `ActionView::Rendering` and `ActionController::ApiRendering`.

`ActiveSupport::Concern` alters standard behaviour of `include` and calls it a "dependency management". When you include a `Concern` inside another `Concern` it stores it as a dependency instead of actually including it. Later when you include the outer `Concern` somewhere else, those dependencies (previously not included modules) are included first and after that is included the actual module. This behaviour is achieved by redefining the `append_features` method.

If you later include another `Concern`, it is appended to dependencies but never included into already existing descendants.

```rb
require 'active_support'
module B
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
module A
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include B
end
class API
  include A
end
A.ancestors #[A]
B.ancestors #[B]
A.instance_variable_get(:@_dependencies) #[B]
API.ancestors #[API, A, B, Object, ...]

# if we later try to include a standard Module
# it is correctly recognized as an ancestor to the API Class,
# however adding a new Concern has no effect
module C
end
module D
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
module A
  include C
  include D
end
API.ancestors #[API, A, C, B, Object, ...]
```

Comment: I am using Ruby 3.1. The condition of Rails is to prevent legacy versions. See https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/main/lib/jbuilder/railtie.rb#L12

Comment: @Aymeric I have found the cause and updated my answer

Comment: @Aymeric I see you have also found the cause in the comment to your question. I confirm it is related.